# Getting Active Window Coordinates and Height Width in C#

Tags: c#, window

I just check in some of the posts here, but none were helpful to me.

The thing I am trying to do is to run a background process of Screen Capturing. Now I want a piece of code that would give me the X, Y or any Active/Current Window opened (Say Notepad) and its Height and Width.

Just that and nothing else.

Comment: what platform? silverlight? wpf? winforms? asp.net? console? (etc.)

Comment: that is the version of .net you are using. not your platform. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]  
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();  


private IntPtr GetActiveWindow()  
{  
    IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;  
    return GetForegroundWindow();  
}
```

Then get the window position with GetWindowRect.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]  
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]  
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);  

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  
public struct RECT  
{
    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner  
    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner  
    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner  
    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner  
}
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot. I am just going to test it now :)

Comment: 'private Handle GetActiveWindow() ' This is giving error for Handle :/

Answer (score 3):

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Rectangle lpRect);

    static void Main()
    {
        SetProcessDPIAware();
        Rectangle t2;
        GetWindowRect(GetForegroundWindow(),out t2);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please describe the answers more. Clear answer will help people understand what you mean and will increase the chance of selecting as an answer
.